# Removing each element in a slice

Tags: go

I'm getting some unexpected behavior when I try to loop through a slice and remove every element in sequence to print the remaining elements, using the suggested **Delete** method from [SliceTricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks). For example, when I try and loop through a slice that contains the letters `[A B C]`, I expect the output to be `[B C]`, `[A C]`, `[A B]` in that order:

**Method 1**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []string {"A", "B", "C"}
    for i, _ := range a {
        fmt.Println(append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...))
    }
}
```

However, the output here is surprising to me. It outputs `[B C]` three times.

I did eventually get my expected behavior by doing the following:

**Method 2**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []string {"A", "B", "C"}
    for i, _ := range a {
        result := make([]string, 0)
        result = append(result, a[:i]...)
        result = append(result, a[i+1:]...)
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

What is causing the unexpected behavior in method 1 and is there a better way to achieve this other than method 2?

Comment: Failure to assign the value from append is usually a mistake

Comment: @JimB Thats a requirement for the OP. The idea is basically just to print a slice and each time remove one of the elements in sequence. OP: This isn't possible with slice indexing and shorthand like this. You'll have to be a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "what" is because [`append(slice, elems...)`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) is actually updating the `slice` with the new elements.  It returns a "new" slice only because it may have had to relocate the original slice due to memory reallocation.  So, in your example code, you are actually changing the contents of `a` with each call to `append`.  (A good overview is in the "Append: An Example" section of [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices) golang blog post).

As to "how", my attempt is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []string {"A", "B", "C"}
    for i, _ := range a {
        result := make([]string, i, len(a)-1)
        copy(result, a[:i])
        result = append(result, a[i+1:]...)
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://play.golang.org/p/Caa_x20_7p)

Initializing `result` with a length and capacity, as well as using `copy` instead of two `append`s attempts to reduce the number of memory reallocations required.

Comment: This gives the best explanation about why the unexpected behavior is occurring and also gives an acceptable alternative. I do prefer the solution that @jimt provides better though.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it without extra allocations, try just swapping out values as shown [in this example](http://play.golang.org/p/2qWA46wxud):

Note that this assumes you are OK with shuffling the list contents.
If not, just copy the list once before the loop and do the same as below.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    set := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    for i := range set {
        set[0], set[i] = set[i], set[0]
        fmt.Println(set[1:])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[b c]
[a c]
[a b]
```

Comment: You can skip the swap in iteration 0 as swapping x[0] with x[0] is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

See what happens after the first iteration:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []string{"A", "B", "C"}
    x := append(a[:0], a[1:]...)
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Gives

```
[B C C]
[B C]
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/2LqBwHejhy

The next two iterations are similar. Just try it out.